# Is Drag and Drop possible in Dgrid without using store

Tags: dojo, dgrid

i am not using store attribute for my Grid and want to implement DnD. Currently the row in my table are drag gable but throws an error when i drop the dragged row. Below is the error.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Dojo documentation mentions that, The store should be order-aware, supporting the options.before parameter on add() and put() calls to properly respond to DnD operations.

So does it mean that DnD can only be implemented using store in Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the way the `DnD` extension is written, it expects to be used with a store.